# Загрузка файла в выбранную папку, из списка папок, с помощью PHP

Tags: php, html

Как реализовать загрузку файлов с возможностью выбрать в какую папку его загрузить? Вот текущая наработка

```
<?php
include 'function.php';
dbConnect();

$password = 'mypass'; // password
$max_upload_size = 1024*1024*2; // max file size

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
    if (!empty($_FILES['file']) and !empty($_POST['password']))
    {   
        // validate password
        if ($_POST['password'] === $password)
        {
            // validate file size
            if ($_FILES['file']['size'] < $max_upload_size) {

                // generate upload path with unique file name
                $path = 'uploads/' . uniqid() . '.';
                $path .= pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

                // move uploaded file to upload directory
                if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path) )
                {
                    // insert new file to mysql db
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (`name`, `path`)
                                VALUES('$name', '$path')");

                    // set success message
                    $message = 'File Uploaded!';

                } else {
                    $message = 'Upload fail';
                }
            } else {
                $message = 'File is too large';
            }
        } else {
            $message = 'Wrong Password!';
        }
    } else {
        $message = 'File not set';
    }
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File download</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Upload File</h1>

        <!--messages-->
        <?php if(isset($message)): ?>
            <p class="alert"><?php echo $message; ?></p>
        <?php endif ?>

        <!--file upload form-->
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload">
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Сделайте ввод папки в форме загрузки. В самом примитивном случае `<select name="folder"><option value="folder1">folder1</option>...` И на сервере используйте $POST['folder'] для вычисления целевой папки.

Comment: @Sergey должно получиться что то вроде того .... http://codepen.io/feeel1/pen/rxWBVX

Comment: НО возникает вопрос как в PHP изменить код, где мне вставить "uploads/" . $_POST["Folder"] ???

Comment: $path = 'uploads/' . uniqid() . '.'; как вот эта строчка должна выглядеть. У меня есть два варианта $path = 'uploads/' . $_POST["Folder"] . uniqid() . '.'; или вот такой вариант $folder = $_POST['Folder']; $path = 'uploads/' . rtrim($folder, '/') . '/' . uniqid() . '.'; какой из них правильный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить в форму

```
   <form>
      <select name="folder">
        <option value="folder1">Folder 1</option>
        <option value="folder2">Folder 2</option>
        <option value="folder3">Folder 3</option>
      </select>
    </form>
```

В обработчик

```
<?
    ...
    $folder = $_POST['folder'];
    ...
    $path = 'uploads/' . $folder . '/' . uniqid() . '.';
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую.